# Rails 5, Turbolinks 5 JQuery Stops Working on Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, turbolinks-5

I've seen this problem posted a few times on here, but none of the solutions work for me, including the one from the Rails Guide.  Is there something wrong with my code below that I'm missing?  Essentially, when a page initially loads, JQuery works, but when you reload the page, everything stops working.  I'm a Rails noob so appreciate your help and patience.

app/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= bootstrap.min.js
//= require_tree .

$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function(){
    $(".full-width").fadeIn(2500);

    $(".index-thumbnails").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.60},"fast")
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1},"fast")
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
    $("#subscribeModal").modal("show"); 
    }, 
    5000
    );

    $(".close").on("click", function(){
        $("#subscribeModal").modal("hide");
    });

    $(".social").mouseover(
        function(){
          $(this).animate({height: 116, width: 116},"fast");
        }
    );

    $(".social").mouseout(
        function(){
          $(this).animate({height: 96, width: 96},"fast");
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Try `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { ... });` removing the `ready` from your call

Comment: I tried that too.  No luck.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Read the [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) docs - especially the part about idempotent event handlers. You should be using delegated event handlers with [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `$(document).on(click, 'selector' ...` instead of attaching handlers directly to elements. Also if this is a Rails 4 application you may actually be using what is now known as turbolinks-classic. The corresponding event in turbolinks-classic is `page:change`

Comment: Also check the console for errors. Sound pretty self evident but you'd be surprised...

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){`
and add the `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` to your gemfile. It'll work.
Check and inform me. I think it should work this time.